# PHP - How to wrap every 2 items of a 'for' loop within a div

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to wrap every too items of this very basic for loop within a div :

```
<?php 

for( $i=1; $i<=50; $i++ )

{
echo "<div><a href='item-".$i."'>".$i."</a></div>";
}
?>
```

This produces the following :

```
<div><a href="item-1">1</a></div>
<div><a href="item-2">2</a></div>
<div><a href="item-3">3</a></div>
<div><a href="item-4">4</a></div>
```

The output i need would be :

```
<div><a href="item-1">1</a> <a href="item-2">2</a></div>
<div><a href="item-3">3</a> <a href="item-4">4</a></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way i can think of is by doing this. This also works if you have a resultset from a database, or an array of item objects, just replace the `range()` function with the array.

```
<?php
    
foreach (array_chunk(range(1, 50), 2) as $chunk) {

    echo "<div>";

    foreach ($chunk as $itemId) {
        echo "<a href='item-" . $itemId . "'>" . $itemId . "</a>";

    }

    echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and gives the result i needed. @Jimmix solution works fine also

Answer (score -1):

Use [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

code:

```
<?php 

$chunks = 2;
$display = true;
for( $i=1; $i<=6; $i++ )
{
    if ($display && ($i % $chunks || $chunks === 1)) {
        echo "<div>";
        $display = false;
        $last = true;
    }

    echo "<a href='item-".$i."'>".$i."</a>";

    if (!($i % $chunks)) {
        echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
        $display = true;
        $last = false;
    }
}

if ($last) {
    echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

generates:

```
<div><a href='item-1'>1</a><a href='item-2'>2</a></div>
<div><a href='item-3'>3</a><a href='item-4'>4</a></div>
<div><a href='item-5'>5</a><a href='item-6'>6</a></div>
```

and with:

```
$chunks = 3;
```

you will get:

```
<div><a href='item-1'>1</a><div><a href='item-2'>2</a><a href='item-3'>3</a></div>
<div><a href='item-4'>4</a><div><a href='item-5'>5</a><a href='item-6'>6</a></div>
```

and so one.

Comment: That would break for `$i` a non-multiple of `$chunks`. Try running it with 5 for example.

Comment: Thank you too @Jimmix i like your solution also. Thank you for your time guys

Comment: @NSTK You are welcome, please accept one of the answers so your question is marked as having a satisfying answer. I think OliverO'Neill answer is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Alright, i accepted Oliver's answer as you suggested. You made it easy for me because you both gave me solutions, so i was uncomfortable picking one instead of the other :)
Thank you again